# Ethernet interface LOWER_UP -> UP

Tags: ubuntu, networking

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715664/using-ip-what-does-lower-up-mean#:%7E:text=LOWER_UP%20indicates%20that%20an%20Ethernet,network%20interface%20to%20be%20enabled.) describes the differences between LOWER_UP and UP where LOWER_UP means the device is plugged in and connected to the network while UP additionally means the ethernet interface is enabled.

The network interfaces work, but **I'm wondering how I go about enabling the network interface**, i.e. changing the state from LOWER_UP to UP. I have a computer with two ethernet interfaces that are in LOWER_UP state.

```
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:2f:74:cb:41:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 1.2.3.5/23 brd 1.2.3.255 scope global dynamic enp5s0
       valid_lft 27726sec preferred_lft 27726sec
    inet6 aaaa::aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enx9cebe801bed3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 01:23:45:67:89:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 1.2.3.4/22 brd 1.2.3..255 scope global enx9cebe801bed3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 bbbb::bbbb:bbbb:bbbb:bbbb/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with the devices configured in netplan. The first is set with a dynamic IP, the second with a static IP. I ran `sudo netplan apply` then `sudo ip link set iface_name down`,  `sudo ip link set iface_name up`

Comment: With those IP addresses, I'm not sure if you _can_ but you shouldn't. They are in the same subnet, which will be problematic. Changing /22 to /23 doesn't change it - /23 is included in /22. If you want to have them in the same subnet, you should create a NIC team and give an IP address to the team, not individual NICs. That way they will show in the network as a single logical interface. I wouldn't be surprised if just the fact that they are in the same subnet is enough to prevent them from coming up.

Comment: Sorry, should specify. Those aren't the actual IP addresses of the interface.  They are just made up IPs. idk, didn't want to post a bunch of info like that on the internet. They are both in the same /23 subnet though.

Comment: If they are in the private ranges (10.x.x.x, 172.16.x.x, 192.168.x.x) there's really no reason to hide them. If they aren't, just change the two first octets to 192.168 and Bob's your uncle :-) In any case if they are in the same subnet I doubt very much they will come up at all. A device can't have more than one logical interface into a single subnet without some extra configuration like NIC teaming, master/backup or so. In case of a computer I'd opt for NIC teaming.